# Why is my code able to compile but part i and part ii have runtime error, while part iii is okay

Tags: java

I have this 7 classes with inheritance relations.

```
public class ClassA {

    public ClassA() {
    }

    public void printer(int x, String y)
    {
        System.out.println("Class A");
    }

}
```

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA{

    public ClassB() {
    }

    public void printer(int x)
    {
        System.out.println("Class B");
    }

}
```

```
public  class ClassC  extends ClassA{

    public ClassC() {
    }

    public void printer(String x, String y)
    {
        System.out.println("Class C");
    }

}
```

```
public class ClassD  extends ClassC{

    public ClassD() {
    }
       public void printer(String a, String b)
    {
        System.out.println("Class D");
    }

}
```

```
public class ClassE extends ClassC{

    public ClassE() {
    }

    public void printer(String x)
    {
        System.out.println("Class E");
    }

}
```

```
public class ClassF extends ClassE{

    public ClassF() {
    }

       public void printer(int x)
    {
        System.out.println("Class F");
    }
}
```

```
public class ClassG  extends ClassE{

    public ClassG() {
    }

           public void printer(String x)
    {
        System.out.println("Class G");
    }

}
```

May I ask why is the following code able to compile and why is there a runtime error for i and ii but iii is okay. I am sorry if this is a easy problem but I have been cracking my brain on this for hours. Thanks!

```
// part i
ClassA a = new ClassC();
ClassG g = (ClassG)a;
g.printer("hello");

// part ii 
ClassA a = new ClassC();
ClassG g = (ClassG)a;
g.printer("hello", "there");

// part iii
ClassA a = new ClassF();;
ClassC f = (ClassC)a;
f.printer(88,"there");
```

Edited:
For part i and ii, the error is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: ClassC cannot be cast to ClassG. My question is about polymorphism, upcasting and downcasting. I need help to understand it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, what is the error???

Comment: I am sorry, i have put it as code already. There is no error, I would like to know why is my code able to compile but there is runtime error for part i and ii while part iii is fine? My question is about polymorphism, upcasting and downcasting. I need help to understand it.

Comment: A runtime error is an error.  If you're going to ask why you're getting an error, you should include the error you're getting in your question (complete stacktrace).

Comment: `ClassG` is not a parent class of  `ClassC` , so you can't cast a `ClassC` instance to a `ClassG` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that inheritance defines an **is-a** relationship between the parent and child class.  Casting on a child class will work if it has a direct link to the parent class.

In this case, it doesn't work.  `ClassG` **is-a** `ClassC` because of inheritance, but there's no guarantee that a `ClassC` **is-a** `ClassG`.

Comment: may I ask why does it even compile at the first place?